# Excel Dynamic Countifs range

Tags: excel, formula, countif

Can a countifs range be dynamic?

I'm simply trying to do a countifs formula in a worksheet that is likely to grow, currently I have the upper bound set to 10000 but since I'm trying to count the number of instances a date appears in a list I have to have a countif formula for every single day of the year. Thats 365 countif formulas all with an upper bound of 10000 and I'm sure at some point in a few months I will have to update it.

Am I able to use Excel formulas much like I could in VBA to declare a dynamic range for my countifs function?

[image: Example of Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your cell range to a table (select your table then Insert > Table) you can refer to the entire column or row with your formula and it will adapt dynamically.

Comment: That makes it unbearably slow if working with whole column ranges, unless once again I convert a select cell range to a table. Which brings us back to square one because then I will run out of table space in the same way.

Comment: If you make a table and use a table formula referencing a field in the entire (as opposed to a worksheet column) it will only apply to the number of cells in the table field.

Comment: Better to normalize the table structure and then use pivot tables to do the work.